# how to center columns based on window width

Tags: javascript, css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />      
<style type="text/css">
        body { position: relative; }

        .contain { position:relative; overflow: hidden; width: 80%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; }     

        .box {
            background-color: #F0F0F0;
            color: #888;
            font-family: Arial, Tahoma, serif;
            font-size: 13px; }

        .box p { padding: 10px; }

        .box span {
            float: left;
            font-size: 26px;    
            font-weight: bold;  }

        div.alt { background-color: #CCC; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myFluidGrid = {
            COLNUMBER : 2, // Minimum column number.
            COLMARGIN : 10, // Margin (in pixel) between columns/boxes.
            COLWIDTH : 240, // Fixed width of all columns.

            doLayout : function() {
                var self = this;
                var pointer = 0;
                var arr = [];
                var columns = Math.max(this.COLNUMBER, parseInt($('body').innerWidth() / (this.COLWIDTH + this.COLMARGIN)));

                $('.box').css('position', 'absolute').css('width', this.COLWIDTH  + 'px');
                $('.box').each(function() {
                    var tempLeft = (pointer * (self.COLWIDTH + self.COLMARGIN));
                    $(this).css('left', tempLeft + 'px');

                    var tempTop = 0;
                    if (arr[pointer]) { tempTop = arr[pointer]; }
                    $(this).css('top', tempTop + 'px');

                    arr[pointer] = tempTop + $(this).outerHeight() + self.COLMARGIN;
                    pointer++;
                    if (pointer === columns) { pointer = 0; }
                });
            }
        };
        $(window).ready(function() {
            myFluidGrid.doLayout();
        }).resize(function() {
            myFluidGrid.doLayout();
        });
    </script>

<div class="contain">    
    <div class="box">This is box number 1...</div> 
    <div class="box">This is box number 2...</div>
    <div class="box">This is box number 3...</div>
</div>
```

Demo of current code: http://grahamthomas.me/temp/test.html

Trying to get the above grid to remain centered in the window no matter its size. I currently have it roughly centered, but when the window size is adjusted, the centering becomes untrue until the new column is populated with content (i.e. when the dynamic grid is between columns--larger than 3 columns, but no quite 4).

I'm not great at JS, but my logic is:

- create a 100% wrapper (which would mimic the body.innerWidth
  dimension in the JS)
- create a centered wrapper inside this (80% for example)
- place the content in the centered wrapper
- once the 100% wrapper is large enough to handle an additional column, append the new  div within the centered wrapper

You can clearly see the overflow:hidden property 'run over' the right-most boxes when dragging the window smaller. I assume from this, the window width isn't being calculated properly. I tried variants of var columns, like:

```
var columns = Math.max(this.COLNUMBER, parseInt(($('body').innerWidth() * 0.8)/ (this.COLWIDTH + this.COLMARGIN)));
```

..which keeps the columns within the window, but still isn't a proper center.

I've been looking at this for a while, anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what your goal is more specifically? I'd check out the jQuery plugin Isotope. I use it often for these custom types of fluid layouts

Comment: @Greg My goal is to have all the boxes that are visible to be centered. So when you have 3 columns, they're centered on the screen, then as you pull the window wider, those 3 columns stay centered until the 4th column pops in. Like Isotope has done here: [http://isotope.metafizzy.co/tests/centered-masonry.html](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/tests/centered-masonry.html)

Answer (score 0):

No JavaScript required:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    text-align: center;
}
div.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -40%;
    width: 80%;
}

div.main div.block {
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    background: #a00;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Although, this example doesn't solve the centering issue when in-between columns, and it's a classic grid so it can't accommodate boxes with varying heights.